# understanding algebraic proof in complex geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-geometry

I am studying "Condensed Mathematics and Complex Geometry" by Dustin Clausen, Peter Scholze. I came across this theorem and this proof:

[image]

I don't understand a lot of steps in the proof. I proved a few steps, including that the kernel of $\vert \cdot \vert$ is an ideal, among other things. However I have missed the whole point of the proof, my two biggest issues being :

1. (Around the red dot in the image), it says "Our goal in then to show that $A=\mathbb{C}$. Does that mean that A is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$? If it is the case, how was this achieved?
2. There isn't much talk of continuity except for the function on the 6th line of the proof. Where, then did they prove anything about a homeomorphism?

Comment: I do not know sadly the  definition of $\mathcal{M}^{berk}$ however, regarding point 1. f is a morphism of $\mathbb{C}$ algebras, in particular if $A/\mathrm{ker}\left(\mid\cdot \mid \right)\cong \mathbb{C}$ we can choose the projection as our $f$, which is unique. The magic here is that ones need to go to ones, and so 1-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebras are always UNIQUELY isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. I also assume, as they are not talking about the induced homeomorphism at all, that that is in their eyes a "trivial" corollary, if you can give me the definition, I can give it a read.

Comment: @Enkidu Thank you very much for your answer, it makes some things much clearer. $\mathcal{M}_{k}(A)$ is the set of multiplicative bounded semi-norms on A i.e : 

    * $\vert . \vert : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$

    * $\forall (a,b) \in A^2, \vert a-b \vert \leq \vert a \vert + \vert b \vert$

* $\vert 0 \vert=0$

* $\forall (a,b) \in A^2, \vert ab \vert= \vert a \vert \vert b \vert$
    
* $\exists C>0, \forall a \in A, \vert a \vert \leq C \vert a \vert_0$